# Using mapping variables in a post-session command

Tags: informatica

Workflow generates three files (header, detail, trailer) which I combine via post-session command. There are two variables which are set in my mapping, which I want to use in the post-session command like so:

```
cat header1.out detail1.out trailer1.out > OUTPUT_$(date +%Y%m%d)_$$VAR1_$$VAR2.dat
```

But this doesn't work and the values are empty, so I get OUTPUT_20151117__.dat.

I've tried creating workflow variables and assigning them via pre-session variable assignment, but this doesn't work either.

What am I missing? Or was this never going to work?

Answer (score 0):

Can you see the values assigned to those variables on the session log or do they appear empty as well?

Comment: The values do show up at the start of the run when the persistent values are retrieved from the repository, and again at the end when the new values are saved to the repository.

Comment: I assume your mapping variables are retrieved from the repository but are never transferred up to the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Creating workflow variables is what I'd try, but you need to assign the values with the **post**-session variable assignment.

Comment: I tried that as well, but still no dice. I concluded that workflow and mapping variables couldn't be used in a post-session command, and found a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you store values in a variable in your mapping and pass the values up to the workflow after the session succeeded. Here is how you can achieve that:

1. Define a Workflow variables $$VAR1 and $$VAR2
2. Define the variables in your mapping, but chose different names! So i.e. $$M_VAR1 and $$M_VAR2
3. In your mapping, assign the values to your mapping variables through the functions SetVariable(var as char, value as data type)
4. In your session, select Post-session on success variable assignment.

In step 4, the current value from $$M_VAR1 (mapping variable) is stored in your workflow variable $$VAR1 and can then be used in the workflow in command tasks like you asked.

A few notes:

- I'm not 100% sure if the variable assignment is exectured before the post-session command. If the command is executed first, you could execute your command tasks in an external command task after your session.
- Pre-Session variable assignment is used if you pass a value from a workflow variable down to a mapping variable. You can use this if your variables $$VAR1 or $$VAR2 are used inside another mapping and need to be initialized at the beginning.